# How to insert a different delimiter in between two columns in shell

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I 've a file as below

```
ABc def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
0 2930|0|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
```

Now, i want to split the first column with the same delimiter.

output:

```
ABc|def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
0|2930|0|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
```

Please help me out  with awk.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
$ sed 's/ /|/' file
ABc|def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
0|2930|0|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
```

The way it is defined, it just replaces the first space with a `|`, which is exactly what you need.

With `awk` it is a bit longer:

```
$ $ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{split($1, a, " "); $1=a[1]"|"a[2]}1' file
ABc|def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
0|2930|0|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
```

After definining input and output field separator as `|`, it splits the first field based on space. Then prints the line back.

Comment: `Sed` gives me: `| ABc def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|` for first line.

Comment: I guess you copy pasted with leading spaces. I see the original post has ones, I guess by mistake.

Comment: Where did `2930` go in your `awk` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/ /,"|")}1' file
ABc|def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
0|2930|0|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
```

Without the leading space, this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to replace the delimiter (space->pipe) in **first** column.

It could happen that in your first col, there is no space, but in other columns, there are spaces. In this case, you don't want to do any change on that line. Also in your first column, there could be more spaces, I guess you want to have them all replaced. So I cannot think of a shorter way for this problem.

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{gsub(/ /,"|",$1)}7' file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/  /;/^\([^|]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^|[[:blank:]]\)/ s//\1|\2/'
```

assuming first column is blank for empty, a blank (or several) as the separator than another non blank or |
this allow this

```
ABc def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
 def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
ABc|def|0|0|0| 1 | 2| 9|
```

Comment: at least add a comment if thumb down to understand why, thnks