# Removing spaces after and before commas (not between words) using command line

Tags: regex, csv, sed

I have a CSV file that is created using `pull_data $a $b > $id.csv`.

**An e.g. of a line from the output is:**

```
1041894,30/01/2013,31/01/2013,A Customer Limited , 2, 1,PR14, PR14 , 104 An Item ,247 An Item
```

**Here is my condition:**

- I need to remove all spaces after or before the commas but exclude spaces that are between words.
- I need each line to look like the below and would like to use sed if possible:

`1041894,30/01/2013,31/01/2013,A Customer Limited,2,1,PR14,PR14,104 An Item,247 An Item`

I have tried `sed 's/, \+\| \+,/,/g'` but this does not remove all the spaces after or before a comma, it removes only some.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove spaces between commas using command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553402/remove-spaces-between-commas-using-command-line)

Comment: There are some correct answers below, but if the fields are sometimes quoted (perhaps there are commas in some of the data) then this becomes much more difficult to handle completely with a regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

Try this sed:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/,[[:space:]]\+/,/g' -e 's/[[:space:]]\+,/,/g' file
```

OR this awk:

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*' '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, file
```

#### UPDATE:

OP might have *whitespaces* not just spaces:

Try this sed also:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,/g' file
```

Comment: Your new regex look very similar to the one I posted ;)

Comment: Like you did with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21430976/1983854) based on mine on `sed`, @Jotne ?

Comment: @Jotne: I posted 3 alternatives after trying out various tests. One or two may look similar since approach is similar.

Comment: @anubhava I have tried `sed -i.bak 's/ *, */,/g' file` but it does not remove any spaces in the file? I still have `,     1` etc.

Comment: Should have worked. Have you tried 2 other alternatives I posted?

Comment: if the first or last column has leading and trailing space, above commands will be failed to handle

Comment: @BMW: Requirement is to remove spaces around commas only

Comment: @anubhava This `awk -F'[, ]+' '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, ` removes all spaces in my test and changes `A Customer Limited` to `,A,Customer,Limited`

Comment: @Jotne: Tanks, Yes realized and fixed it. Also I suspect OP might have tabs also so updates all 3 alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Some like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,",")}1' file
```

```
echo "1041894,30/01/2013,31/01/2013,A Customer Limited , 2, 1,PR14 ,PR14 ,104 An Item ,247 An Item" | awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,",")}1'
1041894,30/01/2013,31/01/2013,A Customer Limited,2,1,PR14,PR14,104 An Item,247 An Item
```

It does remove any space before or after `,`

Edit: added `[[:space:]]` to remove all types of spaces.

Comment: I think you need run the funcution in gsub()

Comment: @BMW Copy and paste error, example did have correct `()`  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $i)}1' file
```