# php remove whitespace during export to csv

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm having trouble with my php script to trim the whitespace from within values as i output the results of a query from postgresql. the commented line is the returned array from a `print_r();`

```
<?php

$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=test password=test");
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'test'");
$array = pg_fetch_all($result);

//Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_number] => 214 [country] => Zanzibar [sector] => Unguja [site] => Chumbe Island Coral Park (CHICOP) [username] => n ) [1] => Array ( [id_number] => 213 [country] => Zanzibar [sector] => Unguja [site] => Chumbe Island Coral Park (CHICOP) [username] => n )

//*************
$array_explode = explode(",", $array);
$array_trimmed = array_map("trim", $array_explode);
$array_implode = implode(",", $array_trimmed);
unset($array_explode);
//*************

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($array_implode as $fields) {

fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);


?>
```

If i remove the lines between the stars then the csv outputs (just with a whole lot of unnecessary whitespace. I have tried both with and without the `implode()`. this has been driving me up the wall and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use `explode` on an array. `explode` is used to split a string into an array of tokens

Comment: @Phil, i used explode to get at the individual values in the array.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. The aptly named `$array` is already an array

Comment: @Phil any suggestions then? I'm relatively new at this and have been presented with data with lots of whitespace in the values, blowing out the exported file size to 1.5mb for a 400 line csv

Comment: here is the link that helps you.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575764/removing-spaces-after-and-before-commas-not-between-words-using-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using your code:

```
<?php
$array = Array (0 => Array ( 'id_number' => 214, 'country' => 'Zanzibar', 'sector' => 'Unguja', 'site' => 'Chumbe Island Coral Park (CHICOP)', 'username' => 'n'),
        1 => Array ( 'id_number' => 213, 'country' => 'Zanzibar', 'sector' => 'Unguja', 'site' => 'Chumbe Island Coral Park (CHICOP)', 'username' => 'n'));

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($array as $fields) {
        $array_trimmed = array_map("trim", $fields);
        fputcsv($fp, $array_trimmed);
}
fclose($fp);
```

output from file.csv:

```
214,Zanzibar,Unguja,"Chumbe Island Coral Park (CHICOP)",n
213,Zanzibar,Unguja,"Chumbe Island Coral Park (CHICOP)",n
```

Comment: @rmctrazier thanks for the response. I perhaps should have taken out the commented array as i was just using it to test (i will take it out now to save any further confusion). The `$array` value in the code passes an array of values which i will also edit into the original codeblock instead.

Comment: @rmctrazier thanks again for the response, question though, there is nothing in there to trim whitespace? i do appologise as i think i output about the only values without whitespace!

Comment: I updated my answer to include a whitespace trim to fields before being written to the file.